# Shared library name in executable is different than the filename

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

A cleaned up version of my compile command looks like `gcc -o semantic_seg -Wl,-rpath,...  -l:libnvrtc-5e8a26c9.so.10.1 ...` and I have a dynamic library file named exactly `libnvrtc-5e8a26c9.so.10.1` in the directory specified by the `-rpath` flag. The command succeeds.

When I go to run my program, it says `semantic_seg: error while loading shared libraries: libnvrtc.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and when I do `ldd` it shows `libnvrtc.so.10.1 => not found`.

So the problem looks like the name of the shared library in the executable is not the same as the filename. Could that be true? Did the `5e8a26c9` part of the name somehow get stripped off?

Update: Creating a symbolic link `libnvrtc-5e8a26c9.so.10.1 -> libnvrtc.so.10.1` allows the executable to run. But I'm still not sure the mechanism that causes this name modification to happen. It seems a bit magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could that be true?

This is often true.

On ELF systems, the linker uses `SONAME` of the library (if it has one) and *not* its filename to record a runtime dependency.

Running `readelf -d libnvrtc-5e8a26c9.so.10.1 | grep SONAME` will likely show that in fact that library does have `SONAME`, and the value of `SONAME` is `libnvrtc.so.10.1`.

This used to be very convenient for [external library versioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter5-5.html).

**Update:**

> it allows you to link against a library which will be different than the one which will used at run time, but why would I ever want that?

Like I said, it's useful for external library versioning and ABI evolution.

Suppose you ship version 1.0 of `libfoo.so`. You provide `libfoo.so` as a symlink to `libfoo.so.1`, and you use `libfoo.so.1` as `SONAME`.

Any program that links with `gcc main.c -lfoo` (note: no funny `-l:libfoo.so.1` syntax required) will record `libfoo.so.1` as its external dependency, and will use that name at runtime.

Time passes, and you are ready to ship version 2, which is not ABI-compatible.

You don't want to cause all your end-users to change their link line, and you don't want to break any existing binaries.

With the `SONAME`, this is trivial: new package will include `libfoo.so.2` with `SONAME` of `libfoo.so.2`, and a symlink `libfoo.so` now pointing to `libfoo.so.2`.

Voila: both requirements are achieved: existing binaries continue to use `libfoo.so.1`, newly-linked binaries use `libfoo.so.2`, no `Makefile` changes required.

Comment: You were right! The library has a SONAME inside of it. I'm still having a hard time thinking of when this feature would be useful. I can see it allows you to link against a library which will be different than the  one which will used at run time, but why would I ever want that?

Comment: @Mark I've updated the answer to (hopefully) explain why this was useful (still is useful on systems that don't support GNU symbol versioning extension).

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks!